# VTK display multiple images

Tags: image, vtk

Does someone knows how to display multiple images using ActiViz or VTK?

I have a RenderWindowControl, I would like to either display all the images like in a list in there or add multiple RenderWindowControls to display the multiple images..

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You have some choices, for the task of visualize multiple images. I hope that at least one of them represents what you want to achieve:

1- Using [multiple render windows](http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/Examples/Cxx/Visualization/MultipleRenderWindows). Basically, the example provided in the link creates an array of `vtkRenderWindowInteractor` objects, so that you can visualize multiple images.

2 - Using a single [render window with viewports](http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/Examples/Cxx/Visualization/MultipleViewports). The render window is splitted into viewports (`renderer->SetViewport` is the key, here), so that you can visualize `n` images at a time, where `n` is the number of viewports.

3 - Using the ["slices" approach](http://www.paraview.org/Wiki/VTK/Examples/Cxx/IO/ReadDICOMSeries) (the example works on DICOM files). This implements the "list" behaviour, as you said in your question. Basically, you visualize an image at a time, but you can navigate through them simply by pressing the arrow keys. The example derives the `vtkInteractorStyleImage` class to catch the events regarding key pressures.

Comment: Thanks! it is what I'm looking for. Which one would be best to interact with? I basically need to display the images and then the user can click on any to delete or remove from the list..

Comment: Nice question...but with any of the approaches you should do it! You just need to delete the reference to the deleted image and re-render your view. But, if I were you, I should ask other things...As: Do the images have to be displaied at the same time? (you should choose the 2nd approach...). Do you have a lot of images in the list? (I will choose the 3rd, since, even with viewports, you will need a huge monitor to visualize them all...)

Comment: Returning to your question, consider that, with an Interactor, you can catch clicks and key pressures, despite the approach choosen...

Comment: Thanks! it really helps. I have around 200 or 300 images, I was thinking to include a scroll bar if that's possible..

Comment: That way, I recommend to build a project that uses VTK + Qt. They are really powerful togheter. With VTK you can handle the graphical/imaging part, and with Qt you can build a good-looking GUI. I use these tools with C++. It's a little pain to configure all togheter, but there's a guide, if you are interested: http://guitarcplusplus.blogspot.it/2013/02/itk-vtk-qt-on-window-7-64bit-and-visual.html (it's not up-to-date, a new version of VTK is out). By the way, I don't exclude that a slider widget for VTK "alone" exists (out-of-the-box or made by the community).

Comment: That may work for my project. Do you have some experience with ActiViz?

Comment: I'm working on a C# project and using the WindowRenderControl so I guess I will need to create multple WindowRenderControls...